# Let TextEditingController be null in null_safety

Tags: flutter, controller, dart-null-safety

I have converted my project to null-safety Dart 2. I have been working through issues since the conversion. Right now, I need to change this line

```
clientFNameController.text = widget.trxns!['clientFName'];
```

so that

```
clientFNameController.text = null;
```

This is the line where the controller is declared:

```
final clientNameController = TextEditingController();
```

I have tried this

```
clientFNameController?.text = widget.trxns!['clientFName'];
```

and this

```
clientFNameController.text = widget.trxns?['clientFName'];
```

How do I write the this line

```
  clientFNameController.text = widget.trxns['clientFName'];
```

so this can be true

```
clientFNameController.text = null;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set the `text` property of a `TextEditingController` to `null`, since the type of the setter is `String`, not `String?`.

You can use the empty string `""` however. For example, if you wanted your text field to have the text of `widget.trxnw['clientFName']` if it was non-null, and be empty otherwise, you could have something like this:

```dart
String? clientFName = widget.trxnw['clientFName'];
if (clientFName == null) {
  clientFNameController.text = "";
} else {
  clientFNameController.text = clientFName;
}
```

This can be shortened to:

```dart
String clientFName = widget.trxns['clientFName'] ?? "";  // "if null" operator
clientFNameController.text = clientFName;
```

Or shortened even further to:

```dart
clientFNameController.text = widget.trxns['clientFName'] ?? "";
```